# Unix 'at' command and returning a job number

Tags: php, unix

I'm currently using the unix `at` command to schedule jobs in the future. However, I also want to be able to delete these jobs if I deem it necessary. Is there any way to get the job number immediately after the creation of a job? I know that `atq` can show a list of pending jobs but I want to be able to get the job number in PHP code immediately after creating the job. I can run the `atq` command but what if another job is created before I get the last job in the queue? Then I don't have the correct job number.

Long story short, is there any way after creating a job with the `at` command that I can get the job number in return without using the `atq` command?

For example, my code is:

```
exec('echo /usr/bin/php -f /home/site/public_html/test.php | sudo /usr/bin/at now');
```

I'm currently looking over command substitution that one comment suggested to figure out how to get the job number from this php `exec()` code.

When I try

`var=$(echo /usr/bin/php -f /home/site/public_html/test.php | sudo /usr/bin/at now)`

in the shell and `echo $var` I get an empty line. Why doesn't `var` hold the output?

Comment: The command prints a line containing the job number. Redirect the output to a variable with `$(...)` and then extract that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x=exec("echo sleep|at 14:00 2>&1");
$match="";
if(preg_match("/^job\s*(\d+)\s*/",$x,$match)){
    $job= $match[1];
    print "job: ". $job . "\n";
}
```

Comment: The problem at this approach is that "echo sleep" is not only executed at 14:00 but also when you run the script. Is it possible to run it just at 14:00 in your case?

Comment: Why do you think it is executed when you run this script? Only the echo has been executed that time (as far as I know).

Comment: Oh sorry now I understand. "echo" is there just to prevent execution of the sleep at the run of the script. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
exec('at now "php /home/site/public_html/test.php" 2>&1 | grep job | awk "{print $2}", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Help from:

https://superuser.com/questions/368328/have-the-at-command-return-the-job-id-of-the-task-just-submitted